# How to toggle a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a small code where there is a "Add a debit or credit card" button. I have hidden all the content inside that button by default.

Upon click of the button, I want to show the content and again upon click on the button, I want to hide the content.

In my code when I click on the button it disappears and there is no option to toggle again.

```js
$('#addNewCard').hide();
$('#addCard').click(function () {
   $('#addNewCard').show();
   $('#addCard').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn-cal" id="addCard">Add a debit or credit card</button>

<div id="addNewCard">
  <p>Card details here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#addCard').toggle();
```

Will be toggling the visibility of `#addCard`, which is your button.

It should just be:

```
$('#addCard').click(function () {
    $('#addNewCard').toggle();
});
```

Comment: We are 3 seconds apart! 

Comment: Though you managed to type a lot more than me in very little time @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - so maybe it should be yours!!!

Comment: Fair enough... 

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hiding the button, change the button text, also use `.toggle()` for `$('#addNewCard')`:

```js
$('#addNewCard').hide();
$('#addCard').click(function() {
  $('#addNewCard').toggle();
  $('#addCard').text($('#addCard').text() === "Hide Debit Card" ? "Add a debit or credit card" : "Hide Debit Card");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn-cal" id="addCard">Add a debit or credit card</button>

<div id="addNewCard">
  <p>Card details here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen, even for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, i suggest you hide the #addNewCard element using css display none and then toggle visibility correctly with javascript.

```js
$('#addCard').click(function () {
   $('#addNewCard').toggle();
});
```

```js
$('#addCard').click(function () {
   $('#addNewCard').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="addCard">Add a debit or credit card</button>
<div id="addNewCard" style="display:none;">
  <p>Card details here</p>
</div>
```